# Is there a way to know what connection I'm using?

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless

*The reason I ask is because I want to know if I will achive higher speeds if I'm connected to both than just one connection. Also when I'm gaming (on the internet) if I just use the wireless I always drop out after a while, but I don't if I use both!*

I'm connected to both the wireless and the wired connection.

- How can I know what connection I'm using?
- Am I using both at the same time?
- Which one is the one I get my IP-address from?

This was an interesting result of  `nm-tool | route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

I want to know where the "main" amount of packages are sent. So if I'm connected to both I would like to know which one has the most weight put on it?

The router is a **D-link 524**.

Comment: Can you log in to the router and see which way it reports your machine is connected? This might be the simplest way.

Comment: @TomBrossman I'm connected to both connections, that's my problem. It only list information about a IP-address and not if it's wireless or wired connection.

Comment: You won't have a faster connection with both, you still can't exceed the router's connection out on to the Internet and you likely only have one network card anyway. If it's practical, always choose Ethernet over WiFi to minimize latency. Test for yourself with a traceroute or ping the router in Network Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one network connection active at one time (each one with its IP address), it is the routing table that should determine which one is used for a particular request.

If you are using Network Manager, the command

```
nm-tool | grep -i 'device\|state'
```

should give you information about the active connection, and the output of `route` should give you information about which interface is used to reach a particular IP address.

Given your routing table, both interfaces have the same route, but `eth0` is preferred because of a minor metric.

The conclusion should be that you are only using `eth0`, this can be verified with `ifconfig`, look at the `Byte RX` and `Byte TX` fields.

Comment: edited my question with `route` command you suggested.

Comment: @Alvar: edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `ifconfig` when you are connected to both connections. notice the dominating connection since it has a much greater number of packages received and a lot more data received.